# What is "mount"

Tags: mount, disk

what is "mount"? I have a gut feeling it means "make data storage accessible", but what does it really mean? Please specify the cases when "disk is accessible" and "disk is mounted" are different".

Comment: When disk is mounted then only it's accessible otherwise not.

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's get back to the basics:

- When you plug in a memory device, such as a flash drive, the Linux kernel creates a special file for it inside the /dev directory. All your devices are represented by one of those files.
- When this device is not mounted you cannot access/read/write from it.  It's just like a "stand-by" mode, it's ready to be used, but not being used yet.
- When you mount the device you have to specify a mountpoint. This is a very confusing concept for users coming from Windows. In Windows, every memory device has its own root. In Linux, they are always mounted inside of one single root.
- Mounting a memory device is basically "turning it on" from the "stand-by" mode. It is accessible through the specified mountpoint.
- The /mnt directory exists so you can mount things in it. In some distributions (like Ubuntu) there is also a /media directory, for the same purpose.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, I'll limit this answer to usual storage devices like disks and flash drives.

When you plug in your device, its driver makes it accessible as a device node, which to user programs looks like a file: e.g. `/dev/sda`. Now the disk is *already* accessible. You can read and write it. Here's an example of how you could look at its MBR (first 512 bytes) in hexadecimal+ASCII form:

```
sudo head -c 512 /dev/sda | xxd -g1
```

But if you have some files on that device and you want to access them, this low-level look isn't quite satisfactory. You want to involve a [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) driver. For this you mount the device, using `mount` utility. To make it more obvious, I'll specify the file system explicitly in the following command (assuming I've made the correct choice of `ext4`; if not, `mount` will tell you):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ -t ext4
```

After this, your device will be exposed in `/mnt/` in the format user programs expect it: files and directories — instead of just plain sectors.

You may wonder why I used `sda1` instead of `sda` in the command above. It's because between filesystem level and plain sectors level there's a small layer of [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning), and here `sda1` denotes the first partition on device `sda`.

Answer (score 2):

How familiar are you with Windows (or — ugh! — DOS)? 
If you have gotten beyond absolute newbie status on either of them,
you know that your main system secondary storage device (hard disk or SSD)
is called `C:`.  (For simplicity,
I will assume that the computer has only one secondary storage device,
and that it has only one partition.) 
The root directory is `C:\`, and it contains other directories
like `C:\Intel`, `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Users`, and `C:\Windows`. 
These can contain yet another layer of directories; e.g.,
`C:\Program Files\Oracle`, `C:\Users\your_name`, and so on.

- But if you insert an optical disc (CD or DVD) into the appropriate drive,
  it becomes `D:`.  And it also has a root directory,
  `D:\`, and typically subordinate directories like `D:\Install`.
- And if you remember diskettes (“floppy disks”),
  you’ll recall that they were disk `A:` (and, in the really old days,
  you could have a second one, which, naturally, was called `B:`). 
  And the same pattern applies:
  the root directory `A:\` could contain folders like `A:\GAMES` and `A:\WORK`.
- Other removable drives (e.g., USB drives)
  have drive letters beyond `D` (perhaps `F`),
  and the root directory `F:\` could contain folders like `F:\Project1`.
- And if you have network drives,
  they might have drive letters near the end of the alphabet (perhaps `Z`),
  and the root directory `Z:\` could contain folders like `Z:\Project2`.

So your whole computer’s directory layout looked something like this:

```
     A:\                          C:\                             D:\        F:\        Z:\
    ⋰ ⋱                     ⋰  ⋰  ⋱  ⋱                       ⋰         ⋰          ⋰
   ⋰   ⋱               ⋰     ⋰      ⋱     ⋱                 ⋰         ⋰          ⋰
  ⋰     ⋱         ⋰        ⋰          ⋱        ⋱           ⋰         ⋰          ⋰
GAMES   WORK    Intel   Program Files   Users    Windows    Install    Project1    Project2
                             ⋰          ⋰
                           ⋰          ⋰
                         ⋰          ⋰
                     Oracle     user480468
```

So you could have, in principle,
up to 26 independent filesystem directory trees,
each with its own root directory.  And I suppose that works well enough,
especially now that Windows ties them all together in the `Computer`
(previously known as `My Computer`) superfolder. 
(But then again, look at how hard it is to install programs
on a disk other than `C:`, or to move your user directory off `C:`.) 
And note that `Computer` is a pseudo-folder —
you can’t create files or directories in `Computer`.

[Unix has a philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) that includes the concept
[Do One Thing and Do It Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well). 
(Even the name “Unix” [is derived from the prefix “un-” or “uni-”,
meaning “one”](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/55807/unix-history).) 
So it’s not surprising that the designers of Unix
chose to have a *single* filesystem directory tree;
you’re probably familiar with it:

```
                                        /
                               ⋰ ⋰ ⋰  ⋮  ⋱ ⋱ ⋱
                         ⋰   ⋰   ⋰    ⋮    ⋱   ⋱   ⋱
                   ⋰     ⋰     ⋰      ⋮      ⋱     ⋱     ⋱
             ⋰       ⋰       ⋰        ⋮        ⋱       ⋱       ⋱
       ⋰         ⋰         ⋰          ⋮          ⋱         ⋱         ⋱
 ⋰           ⋰           ⋰            ⋮            ⋱            ⋱            ⋱
bin         dev          etc           home           mnt          tmp          usr    …
                                       ⋰                                       ⋰⋱
                                     ⋰                                       ⋰    ⋱
                                   ⋰                                       ⋰        ⋱
                              user48046                                   bin         lib
```

The beauty of this is that you (in your role of system administrator)
can put everything in one partition,
or put `/home` in one partition and `/usr` in another,
and you (in your role of user) can forget about it. 
You don’t need to know what disk (partition) `/usr` is on;
it appears under the one-and-only filesystem root (`/`) regardless. 
The mild drawback is that you (in your role of power user)
must *maintain* this unified filesystem directory tree when you add
(and remove) storage components. 
When you insert a CD or a flash drive, it’s just an entry under `/dev`,
which you probably shouldn’t mess with too much. 
You can do some things with the device node, like run `fsck` or `fdisk`;
or possibly configure it as a dedicated database storage device
(e.g., for Oracle) — because *the disk is accessible*. 
But you can’t access the files (and directories) on it,
because they aren’t in the filesystem yet —
because *the disk is not mounted*.

#### TL;DR

And this is where `mount` comes in. 
`mount` is the command that attaches ***a*** filesystem
(e.g., on a removable device) to ***the*** filesystem
(the one starting at `/`).<sup>1</sup> 
You’ll notice that there is a `/mnt` directory under the `/` directory. 
Conventionally,
transient (removable) filesystem storage devices are mounted onto directories
under `/mnt`; i.e., they are attached to the filesystem there. 
And on some systems,
some devices are automatically mounted when they are detected. 
But, in theory,
you can mount ***a*** filesystem *anywhere* in ***the*** filesystem.
___________
<sup>1</sup> Splitting hairs,
`mount` is a program that calls the `mount()` system call,
which attaches ***a*** filesystem to ***the*** filesystem.

Comment: Well the name of UNIX was intended to be opposite of MULTICS, I suppose, not doing "one" thing :)

Answer (score 0):

When you 'mount' something you are placing access to the file system contained within onto your root file system structure. Effectively giving the files a location. This is similar to the C:/D: drive labels in windows.

Mounting /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/disk1 places all the files and folders contained within the device `standard disk B partition 1` into the directory `/mnt/disk1` where you can access them.

Modern systems have ways to auto-mount drives just as windows auto-mounts drives to drive letters, but the location mounting system in Unix is much more flexible. And unmounting is obviously the removal of the access to those files/folders from that location. You can find out what file systems are mounted by running the command:

```
mount
```

**Involved parts :** mount, umount, fstab (for fixed mounts), udev, gvfs (for automatic mounting)